# Codeigniter: How to change local site URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Been playing with PHP lately using Codeigniter.

I don't quite get how to change the site URL from

> http://localhost/xampp/codeIgniter/

to

> http://vicireports.com/

and redirect me to my main page.

My config.php looks like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://vicireports.com/vicireports/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Need help! Thanks guys!

Comment: I'd go with `$config['base_url'] = 'http://vicireports.com/';` and `$config['index_page'] = '';` .. additionally, you want http, but put https in config, so decide what you want ;)

Comment: Hi.

Thank you. I did that and the page says:
This site can’t be reached

vicireports.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Should I add it on the hostfile?

Comment: try http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/01/Dns-Probe-Finished-NxDomain.html ..hope you're not expecting that name on your localhost to work

Comment: Tried. but didn't seem to work.

Though DNS PROBE isnt the error when I go to
http://vicireports.com, it shows search results instead.

Comment: looks more like a DNS problem here, not CI related

Comment: thank you so much for the help  moped! Appreciated! :)